# Why does adding an $ \epsilon $-transition to a DFA or NFA preserve the regularity of the language?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Does adding an $ \epsilon $-transition to a deterministic finite automata preserve the regularity of the language?

Don't we have one chance to scan the word? If we choose one direction, don't we miss the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A language is regular if and only if there exists a NFA (equivalently a DFA) that recognizes it.

Adding an $\varepsilon$-transition to a NFA (DFAs are special types of NFAs) still results in a NFA, hence both the the language of the original NFA and the language of the modified NFA are regular.